# FactoryGirl: how to handle belongs_to presence validations behind the scenes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, model-associations

I had a factory like the following:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :product do
    name 'John'
  end
end
```

I have a lot of specs using this factory like this:

```
product = create :product
```

I now added a `Product belongs_to :user` association and validate it on presence:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  validates :user, presence: true
end
```

I would have to refactor all my factory calls like this now (or something similar):

```
product = create :product, user: create(:user)
```

This seems like a hassle to me. I'd like FactoryGirl to do this for me automatically. It should be something like this:

- Whenever creating a product, FactoryGirl automatically adds the user:

  - If there's already a user in the DB, it assigns this user
  - If there's no user in the DB, one is created

Is there a good way to do this? I want to avoid querying the DB for the existence of a user whenever a product is created.

Also, it could be dangerous, as an existing user could be destroyed during a test and then would be missing to any subsequent created product.

Are there better patterns for this?

I've seen stuff like validating the ID instead of the object:

```
validates :user_id, presence: true
```

And then simply assigning a non-existent ID when creating the object:

```
product = create :product, user_id: 123456
```

Is this a good pattern?

All my deeply nested/associated resources should have a `belongs_to :user` association soon. I want to avoid having to write `user: create(:user)` (or `user: @user`) everywhere in my specs.

I'm sure there is a well-proven pattern for this...?

Comment: I understand what you mean but I would say its pretty cool not to have too much magic involved :)

Comment: "Also, it could be dangerous, as an existing user could be destroyed during a test and then would be missing to any subsequent created product." Thats the wrong way to think about it. You should be using database_cleaner to clean out the entire database between tests. Even with fixtures you would use a transaction to roll back. Retaining data between tests is dangerous as it can give ordering issues (tests only pass if run in sequence).

Comment: And no - it should not be the way you think. Factories should create unique instances of models. They should not give different output determined by external state (what models preexist).

Answer (score 2):

> It's possible to set up associations within factories. If the factory
>   name is the same as the association name, the factory name can be left
>   out.
>   http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_bot/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Associations

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :product do
    name 'John'
    user
  end
end
```